# How to convert Struct Array to Byte Array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling

It is easy to convert primitive types to bytes by using Buffer.BlockCopy().

But if I have a array of DateTime, which function should I use to convert the DateTime[] to byte[]?

If I have a constant size of struct (which means I can use Marshal to convert struct to byte[]), which way should I use to convert the T[](struct array) to byte[]?

Comment: Do you want the raw in-memory data? or did you want some particular layout / formatting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274035/how-to-convert-a-byte-into-datetime-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362174/tightest-byte-representation-of-yyyymmddhhmmss, [DateTime.ToBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tobinary(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You can't use `Marshal` here, because `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DateTime))` does not work; again: what is the expected output you want here?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The way I get the size of DateTime is the link:http://alexpinsker.blogspot.cz/2011/10/what-is-size-of-datetime-type-in-c.html   I wanna send DateTime[] to network, so I should convert it to byte[] first

Comment: I wanna find a way like Buffer.BlockCopy to convert DateTime[] to byte[] simply and rapidly.

Answer (score 4):

If you are after a copy of the underlying in-memory representation, then one approach is to just access the data `unsafe` - something like:

```
// invent some data
DateTime[] original = new DateTime[10];
for (int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
    original[i] = new DateTime(2014, 1, i + 1);

byte[] blob = new byte[original.Length * sizeof(DateTime)];

fixed (DateTime* src = original)
fixed (byte* dest = blob)
{
    DateTime* typedDest = (DateTime*)dest;
    for(int i = 0; i < original.Length; i++)
    {
        typedDest[i] = src[i];
    }
}
```

However, this is **hugely** dependent upon what you expect the contents of the `byte[]` to be afterwards, and what you intend doing with it.

Comment: I wanna send  a lot of DateTime[] to network , so I need a rapid way to do that.

Comment: @NorSD so... What fornat does your network protocol expect? Would an int-32 or int-64 representing ticks not suffice?

Comment: The previous way I have used is to store as long[](now, we can use Buffer.BlockCopy to byte[]) which is DateTime.Ticks, and it works well.  I don't know weather the size of DateTime is different in 32/64 system.(I think it is always 8 bytes). Now there are huge of DateTime[] , so I wanna find a way to convert them easily and rapidly.   After I convert them to byte[] , I'll send to network by socket. The receiver may be a native c++ client.